# What errors are saved by brevity?

Tags: c++

"C++ Primer" (5th edition) suggests on page 149 that a brief code can be less error-prone than a longer alternative. It brings the following line of code to serve as an example:

```
cout << *iter++ << endl;
```

It claims that the above line is less error-prone than the alternative:

```
cout << *iter << endl;
++iter;
```

To me, even though the meaning of `*iter++` is clear, this expression still requires a non-zero mental effort to parse and so the second version is more readable. So, I want to understand: what is more error-prone about the second version?

Comment: Someone was smoking something when that was written. Clearly the 2nd is unambiguous.

Comment: I think more code.Writing more code leads to more error prone .

Comment: I don't see this code in the book. Are you sure about the page? Which chapter/paragraph is it?

Comment: @Brahim: I don't even own the book. Took me 2 seconds to look it up: http://bit.ly/1GZsL55 (sorry, had to shorten the link for it's too complex)

Comment: Problem here: the actual question / aspect of the question people are focusing on (i.e. the specific code example) has little or nothing to do with the question title. [*In general*, brevity reduces errors](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/185660/is-the-average-number-of-bugs-per-loc-the-same-for-different-programming-languag), often counterintuitively, but this is a bad example in multiple ways (e.g. a second way is that brevity is most useful as a property of whole programs, when combined with abstraction, not so much of single lines).

Comment: Apart from copy-pasting accidents (which should not happen often since you shouldn't be copy-pasting code around too much), I don't see what's wrong with the second code. First one is OK too, since `*i++` is the pretty standard idiom "take one and advance".

Answer (score 22):

I also do not agree with the author.

Usually each code snippet has a tendency to be changed in the future.

For example this statement

```
cout << *iter++ << endl;
```

can be changed the following way

```
cout << *iter++ << ... << SomeFunction( *iter ) << endl;
```

In this case the code will have undefined behaviour because the order of evaluation of function arguments is unspecified.

So in my opinion this code snippet

```
cout << *iter << endl;
++iter;
```

is less error-prone.:)

Introducing side-effects in a code snippet does not make it less error-prone.

Moreover in the code snippet you showed there is no logical relation between the increment of the iterator and outputting its value.

```
cout << *iter++ << endl;
```

So it is unclear why the iterator is incremented in this statement.

Separating this statement into two statements makes the code snippet more clear because it seems that the incrementing is related to some other parts of the code.

The brevity makes the code more expressive. But it does not mean that it necessarily makes also the code less error-prone.:)

Comment: It makes sense if you read `*iter++` as "the next value from iter" - instead of splitting it into two parts "the current value from iter" and "advance iter". ("Next" meaning the first one that hasn't been processed yet, not meaning the one after the current position)

Comment: @immibis  It is usually in the case when the body of the enclosing loop consists of one statement or when this statement is the last statement in the body. Nevertheless in any case nothing prevents to split this statement into two statements.  And the code will be even more readable because you will not need to investigate this statement that to be sure that you did not forget to increment the iterator.:)

Comment: Why didn't you vote to close? If an answer starts with "I disagree with [another answer]", the question clearly is asking for opinions...

Comment: @Jan Dvorak I do not close questions. I answer questions.:)

Comment: @immibis This is why you can define functions in the language. If you want to do "next value from iter" you should write getNext(iter) or iter.getNext(), the compiler will inline the function so no performance hit, but you will have defined behaviour with several getNext() in one statement

Answer (score 5):

The thing is, when you have your function containing a few lines on code, each one of them is treated as a "step" to achieve some goal. When you read such a function you read each line and think what it does and why. In your example,

```
cout << *iter << endl;
++iter;
```

logically could be one step: "when iterating over the container, write each element to `cout`". It's because when you forget either of these lines, the whole step is incorrect. Of course, this very example is not particularly great, because it's not hard to come up with a code, in which the two lines are two different logic steps. However, I assume the author meant, that by writing

```
cout << *iter++ << endl;
```

you protect yourself from forgetting one part of a logic step as well as you make a signal for a reader that this is one logic step.

Comment: +1. If this is what the authors of "C++ Primer" meant, then it's too bad they did not spell this out. This would be an important lesson to the reader.

Comment: From the book referring to that piece of code: "It
is worthwhile to study examples of such code until their meanings are
immediately clear. Most C++ programs use succinct expressions rather than
more verbose equivalents. Therefore, C++ programmers must be comfortable
with such usages. Moreover, once these expressions are familiar, you will find
them less error-prone."

Comment: That basically means "Write bad code to understand bad code"

Answer (score 4):

I can think about the lines being reordered for some reason (maybe they became separated by some other code and it was later modified), or an if/for/while being added, either without braces or with them wrongly placed:

```
++iter;
cout << *iter << endl;

if (some_condition)
cout << *iter << endl;
++iter;

while (something_happens)
{
cout << *iter << endl;
}
++iter;
```

In this small example, the bugs are quite obvious, but that may not be the case when you have a lot more lines.

(And yes, I know the indentation in the 2nd and 3rd examples should be corrected, but sadly I've seen lots of examples like these).

Comment: These types of problems can be addressed at least as effectively in other ways - including use of functions (to contain specified functionality, and be the place to look when that functionality gets broken), and using carefully selected design and coding guidelines (indenting, use of blocks, etc).

Comment: I never said otherwise :-) I just tried to answer the question: "what is more error-prone about the second version?", thus enumerating the possibilities.

Answer (score 4):

I couldn't disagree with the author more.

The expression `*iter++` does two different things to `iter` - it dereferences it and increments it.    Yes, the order is defined, but understanding the results of two actions on a single variable in a single expression requires inherently more brainpower than something which has only one effect on a single variable.

One of the most reliable ways to increase errors from a developer is to unnecessarily increase the brainpower needed to understand what their code actually does.

The virtue of breaking the effects into two distinct statements is that it is easier to understand.

The other phenomenon is that programmers who are taught to include two effects on a single variable in a single statement are more likely to craft expressions with even more effects on some poor variable.    Apart from making their code even less comprehensible, it also increases the likelihood of undefined behaviour (since any expression that modifies any variable more than once in a single expression has undefined behaviour).

Comment: I think the point the author is trying to make is illustrated in @JavierNoval's answer.

Comment: The book's example and reasoning also tends people to believe that if that example is "good", then similarly `Write(*iter++);` is good.  Then `Write2(*iter++, *iter++);` is likewise "good".  But this 3rd example is extremely bad.

Comment: @staticx:  The fact I disagree with the point the author is making does not mean I'm failing to understand it.

Comment: I think that the reason the author brought it up in that manner is because the reasons described in @JavierNoval's answer which is not described in yours.

Answer (score 3):

It might be worth comparing to similar constructs in other languages.

In python, to iterate over a sequence, we use a generator. There is essentially only one operation you can do with a generator: call `next` which obtains an element and advance the generator. Iteration, when done manually, is done by repeatedly calling `next`  to get the terms of the sequence until it raises `StopIteration` to signal the end of the sequence.

In java, to iterate over a sequence, we us an `Iterator`. There is essentially only one operation you can do with an iterator: call `next` which obtains an element and advances the iterator. Iteration, when done manually, is done by repeatedly calling `next`  to get the terms of the sequence until `hasNext` returns `false` to signal the end of the sequence.

In C/C++... we often want to get an element and advance through the sequence. It has been long established (AFAIK before C++ even existed) that this operation is `*p++`.

The only reason we are even contemplating the idea of breaking this into two steps -- one step being to get the current element and the other step being to advance to the next term -- is an artifact of an *implementation detail*.

In a situation where one is *truly* thinking of these two steps as being separate, independent things, then it would be best to keep them as separate expressions.

But it is relatively well established that that is *not* how people are thinking -- people are thinking in terms of "getting an element and advancing the iterator". Iteration, when done manually, is done by repeatedly invoking `*iter++` to get the terms of the sequence, until `iter == end_iter` returns true to signify the end of the sequence.

When thinking this way, splitting the one conceptual step into two syntactically separate elements (`*iter` and `++iter`) is more error prone than keeping it as a single step.

Answer (score 2):

Not a good example, because you shouldn't use while without braces, but it could lead to errors like this: In this case you would have an infinite loop when adding the while.

```
while (*iter)
  cout << *iter << endl;
  ++iter;
```

I think it is a bad example! Much better would be an example, where you have multiple dependent steps. Then someone copies some steps to another function, but misses some lines, which don't look they are semantically needed.

Comment: You might want to add braces, because as it stands you will get stuck in an infinite loop. Semicolons imply you are not using Python.

Comment: @lebbie that was kind of the point of this answer. Brevity would save you, if all code is on one line, you are ok even without braces. - But this is a weak point, since you should always use braces. But it's the same with copy&paste, with several lines you could miss something

Comment: Sorry :) My bad, I didn't read your answer properly.